# How much time has passed in House of Cards?

Tags: house-of-cards

The beginning of *House of Cards* starts with the inauguration of the President. How much time do each of the seasons cover?

<sup>Spoiler'ing season 3 if included would be nice, though I'm currently curious as to how far it's been from the up to the beginning of this season.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can find a timeline of the show [here](http://house-of-cards.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline) if you're interested. To summarise the main points:

- Season 1: Starts January 2013.
- Season 3: He is sworn in on the 28th October 2014.

According to Zoe's [Wiki](http://house-of-cards.wikia.com/wiki/Zoe_Barnes), her date of death is November 5, 2013 - however, I can't see *where* this information is being populated from. I'll do some more digging and edit this answer if I can find something more substantial.

Comment: What's the Season 1-2 border?

Comment: Impossible. Season 1 Ep. 4, 16:30, when Franc visits Russo, the latter has two children about 5-7 y.o. Russo didn't have any children even in previous episode, when he decided to quit narcotics.